# Ruby URI.enocde with Google Maps encoded polylines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps, encoding

Ruby URL encoding seems to be messing up URLs for Google Maps Static API.

here is the un escaped URL.

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=400x400&path=weight:3%7Ccolor:orange%7Cenc:`qdlEa`zh[?@?????@???????????@????A??@???????????????A?AAA?A@CBCBC@EDE@C@C?E@C?A??AA?AAA?A@@??@A???AA????@?@@@@BBB@BDD@BBBDD??@??@B@@@BBD@B@B?D?B?DADCFCDEBGDIBIBG@EBG@E@G?EAEAECEEIGAG?GBKHEFEJEJELEJCJCJEJEJCH?@?@???@??A?C@EBG@G@E@C?GBIDKHILGR?XBLFFFBF?JCDGDMDMDSFQHWLQLSNMRSJKFI@I@KAIEMGEE@GDIJMPMRQTMRW`@MPET?LBFBDB@D?FCFGHKFOFSJQRWFKDE@EBA@EDCBE@EBEBEDEFGDCHENKJMHQ?OCEA?E@CHMJMLSLQHSLIHA@A@A@???@????A?@ADCDEDEBCBA@?BB?FADCDCBABCDEDEFEDGHGFGFEDCBCBA@C@E@GBIBGHEDAB?D@@B@D@BABCBMDMHKFCBABCDCDA@A@A@A?A@CBEDEFAD?FADADABCDE@E?IAGGGECE?I@GHCFEJEJKNMHQFMHIHCL?JBFBBF?DALKJIFIJIFIHIBC?A?A@CBEFIJ?FDL@BC@GACG?K?M?ODQDQCCODKJALDFHDDHDD@B@@BCFEDGBGBIDKBIFIFMJKHKJIRALBLDFF?DCDIFKFMFOFSFOFUFQFK@A?AD@D@DH@LGNKBGEAI@GDCDA@CACAAC@IDIDMLMHGN?J@HBDDBD?DADEFOBMBIBI@EBEBAB?D?F@FB@B?BA@E?ECGCGCGCGCE?E?G?I?GEACAA?AAC???A???A???A???A?AAAACCCAEACAAACCEAC?C?CAAAAA?A?@C@C@G?E?A???A????????A@????????????????????????A???????????????????????????????????
```

once i encoded with URI.encode its not parsed correctly with the Google Maps API.

here is the encoded URL string

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=400x400&path=weight:3%257Ccolor:orange%257Cenc:%60qdlEa%60zh[?@?????@???????????@????A??@???????????????A?AAA?A@CBCBC@EDE@C@C?E@C?A??AA?AAA?A@@??@A???AA????@?@@@@BBB@BDD@BBBDD??@??@B@@@BBD@B@B?D?B?DADCFCDEBGDIBIBG@EBG@E@G?EAEAECEEIGAG?GBKHEFEJEJELEJCJCJEJEJCH?@?@???@??A?C@EBG@G@E@C?GBIDKHILGR?XBLFFFBF?JCDGDMDMDSFQHWLQLSNMRSJKFI@I@KAIEMGEE@GDIJMPMRQTMRW%60@MPET?LBFBDB@D?FCFGHKFOFSJQRWFKDE@EBA@EDCBE@EBEBEDEFGDCHENKJMHQ?OCEA?E@CHMJMLSLQHSLIHA@A@A@???@????A?@ADCDEDEBCBA@?BB?FADCDCBABCDEDEFEDGHGFGFEDCBCBA@C@E@GBIBGHEDAB?D@@B@D@BABCBMDMHKFCBABCDCDA@A@A@A?A@CBEDEFAD?FADADABCDE@E?IAGGGECE?I@GHCFEJEJKNMHQFMHIHCL?JBFBBF?DALKJIFIJIFIHIBC?A?A@CBEFIJ?FDL@BC@GACG?K?M?ODQDQCCODKJALDFHDDHDD@B@@BCFEDGBGBIDKBIFIFMJKHKJIRALBLDFF?DCDIFKFMFOFSFOFUFQFK@A?AD@D@DH@LGNKBGEAI@GDCDA@CACAAC@IDIDMLMHGN?J@HBDDBD?DADEFOBMBIBI@EBEBAB?D?F@FB@B?BA@E?ECGCGCGCGCE?E?G?I?GEACAA?AAC???A???A???A???A?AAAACCCAEACAAACCEAC?C?CAAAAA?A?@C@C@G?E?A???A????????A@????????????????????????A???????????????????????????????????
```

i also tried the encoding in Addressable Gem. I get the same problem. if i identify the invalid URL chars and replace it manually with gsub. it seems to work, but that doesn't seem like a solution.

Comment: Never encode the whole URL, encode each individual component. The `%` in the original URL is supposed to be there, and should not be transformed into `%25`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
require 'cgi'

  unescaped_url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=400x400&path=weight:3%7Ccolor:orange%7Cenc:`qdlEa`zh[?@?????@???????????@????A??@???????????????A?AAA?A@CBCBC@EDE@C@C?E@C?A??AA?AAA?A@@??@A???AA????@?@@@@BBB@BDD@BBBDD??@??@B@@@BBD@B@B?D?B?DADCFCDEBGDIBIBG@EBG@E@G?EAEAECEEIGAG?GBKHEFEJEJELEJCJCJEJEJCH?@?@???@??A?C@EBG@G@E@C?GBIDKHILGR?XBLFFFBF?JCDGDMDMDSFQHWLQLSNMRSJKFI@I@KAIEMGEE@GDIJMPMRQTMRW`@MPET?LBFBDB@D?FCFGHKFOFSJQRWFKDE@EBA@EDCBE@EBEBEDEFGDCHENKJMHQ?OCEA?E@CHMJMLSLQHSLIHA@A@A@???@????A?@ADCDEDEBCBA@?BB?FADCDCBABCDEDEFEDGHGFGFEDCBCBA@C@E@GBIBGHEDAB?D@@B@D@BABCBMDMHKFCBABCDCDA@A@A@A?A@CBEDEFAD?FADADABCDE@E?IAGGGECE?I@GHCFEJEJKNMHQFMHIHCL?JBFBBF?DALKJIFIJIFIHIBC?A?A@CBEFIJ?FDL@BC@GACG?K?M?ODQDQCCODKJALDFHDDHDD@B@@BCFEDGBGBIDKBIFIFMJKHKJIRALBLDFF?DCDIFKFMFOFSFOFUFQFK@A?AD@D@DH@LGNKBGEAI@GDCDA@CACAAC@IDIDMLMHGN?J@HBDDBD?DADEFOBMBIBI@EBEBAB?D?F@FB@B?BA@E?ECGCGCGCGCE?E?G?I?GEACAA?AAC???A???A???A???A?AAAACCCAEACAAACCEAC?C?CAAAAA?A?@C@C@G?E?A???A????????A@????????????????????????A???????????????????????????????????"

  encoded_url = CGI.escape unescaped_url.force_encoding('ASCII-8BIT')
```

Comment: this makes the URL too long. there is a limit to URL length

Comment: I just shorten your URL using https://goo.gl/ link.
then use that unescaped_url & to generate your encoded_url.